# how to subscribe a WebSocket in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, websocket

I want to try to subscribe and listen a 3rd party websocket(endpoint -> wss://...) in google cloud platform.

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Do you have issues? Did you try? If so, with which service? with which context?

Comment: yes I do. I couldn't find the correct way.. I tried pub/Sub, cloud functions, cloud run..i need a right way to start

Comment: Please provide more details about your use case, also, please add details about your attempts and issues to your question.